# Handling Enums with FlowType

Tags: enums, flowtype

```
export type Size =
| 'small'
| 'medium'
| 'large'
| 'big'
| 'huge';
```

Defining the `Size` type like this gives me auto-completion in my IDE wherever I use it:

[image]

Yet, I also want to make use of these values inside of a component: let's say a dropdown menu w/ available size values.

In order to achieve that I am maintaining a **sizes** object out of which I can extract the **Size** FlowType by leveraging **$Keys**:

```
export const sizes = {
  small: 'small',
  medium: 'medium',
  large: 'large',
  big: 'big',
  huge: 'huge',
};

export type Size = $Keys<typeof sizes>;
```

It kind of works in that it points out invalid values for a prop:
[image]

Yet, this solution comes at a cost: it screws all my **auto-completion goodness**... :( Is there a better way to handle Enums in FlowType?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a neat use of `$Keys`!

I don't know of a better way to derive the `Size` type from an object. Maybe you could work in the other direction like this:

```
export type Size =
| 'small'
| 'medium'
| 'large'
| 'big'
| 'huge';

export const sizes: { [key: string]: Size } = {
  small: 'small',
  medium: 'medium',
  large: 'large',
  big: 'big',
  huge: 'huge',
};
```

or perhaps eliminate a bit of duplication this way:

```
export const sizes: { [key: string]: Size } = [
  'small',
  'medium',
  'large',
  'big',
  'huge'
].reduce((obj, s) => {
  obj[s] = s
  return obj
}, {})
```

Clearly that uses more boilerplate. But with the type constraint on `sizes` you at least get a check that prevents invalid strings from getting into the `sizes` object.

Comment: I needed to think about this, sorry. But yes, I agree this is a very neat way to solve this. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks (I like the first approach better though, the second is too cryptic, takes to much energy to quickly parse it in my brain to quickly understand what is actually going on)

Comment: @jessie-hallett this works great, BUT unfortunately if I annotate my objects like that, editors like vscode and atom loose autocomplete capability on the properties that exist on an object. Is there a remedy for that problem?

Comment: I filed a ticket for the autocomplete problem, if you'd like to follow up have a look :) https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues/5431